# Why is "Input string was not in a correct format." in the query in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

In the following code,
I get a run time error of 
"Input string was not in a correct format." after oCommand.ExecuteReader().

```
                    oCommand.CommandText = "CheckOutItem";
                    oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenLargeSizeName", Enum.GetName(typeof(Size), Size.REGULAR));
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenSmallSizeName", Enum.GetName(typeof(Size), Size.SMALL));
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude",oOrder.OrderTimeLocation.Location.latitude);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude",oOrder.OrderTimeLocation.Location.longitude);

                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListingID", MySqlDbType.Int64);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", MySqlDbType.Int16);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryMethod", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                foreach (var OrderItem in oOrder.OrderItems)
                {
                    oCommand.Parameters["@ListingID"].Value = OrderItem.ListingID;
                    oCommand.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value = OrderItem.Quantity;
                    oCommand.Parameters["@Size"].Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(Size), OrderItem.Size);
                    oCommand.Parameters["@DeliveryMethod"].Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(DeliverMethod), OrderItem.DeliveryPickupMethod);

                    using (var reader = oCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Int64 OrderItemID = Convert.ToInt64(reader["@ORDER_ITEM_ID"]);
                            Int64 OrderItemStatusID = Convert.ToInt64(reader["@ORDER_ITEM_STATUS_ID"]);
                            Int64 OrderItemPriceID = Convert.ToInt64(reader["@ORDER_ITEM_PRICE_ID"]);
                            TotalOrderCostFromDB = TotalOrderCostFromDB + Convert.ToDecimal(reader["@TOTAL_ORDER_COST"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

if I use statements like

```
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListingID",OrderItem.ListingID)
```

works fine but I can not loop.

All the values I am assigning are correct in debugging and no nulls or weird stuff getting into .Value.

Since I get the correct answer in AddWithValue method, I don't think I have any issue with StoredPoocedure.

Is there a better approach to loop for this purpose?

After some debugging, I was able to narrow down the issues to last two lines

```
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryMethod", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
```

If I initialize this with a dummy string, everything is fine. But initializing with VarChar or String cause problems. 
For my understanding, following returns a string right?

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(Size), OrderItem.Size)
```

Comment: What you mean you cant loop?

Comment: If I have addwithvalue in loop, it says item already added. So I have to change only value in the foreach loop.

Comment: are you sure you can change the parameter value in the loop? I always create a new command.

Comment: you should create a new command object for each query you want to run, it's simpler to manage. You can't keep adding the same parameters over and over again to the same command object. If you need to add some of parameters the same to every command you create, with the same values each time, then you can easily move that bit into a separate method and just call it each time within your loop, passing in the new command object.

Comment: I already did oCommand.Parameters["@ListingID"].Value = OrderItem.ListingID that few times and did not cause problems. My commandText is same only value changes for fixed set of Parameter names.